# Admin account lost in windows 11. (To continue, enter an admin username and password)

Tags: windows, user-accounts, administrator

I have updated to windows 11 and I wanted to delete oracle so after deleting the registry files I tried accessing users and groups from computer management but was unable to delete the db user. By mistakenly later I might have deleted some registry files related to admin account and now I am unable to run any app as an administrator. I am getting the below popup. I think so my admin account got deleted. Is there some way that I can make my current account as admin account? I tried though commands and other ways but everytime its asking me for username and password without any fields. like below.
Please excuse me if the question is beginner level. I am not much aware of the system related settings.
Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkYnc.jpg)

Comment: Did you get your admin user restored?   Not clear.

Comment: Do you know what keys you deleted? Is there another admin account on the computer? Are these Microsoft accounts on this computer, or local only?

Comment: I got it resolved. Thank you for the help.